# Singlar Points of Complex Function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Stumbled on a practice problem set, and there was this question:

Determine the singular points of the function and state why
the function is analytic everywhere except at those points:

a.) $f(z)= \frac{2z+1}{z(z^3+1)}$ (I'm not sure on how to deal with the $z^3$ term)

b.) $f(z)= \frac{z^3+i}{z^2-3iz+2}$ (I am totally lost on on how to simplify the denominator)

Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* In both cases, the singular points are the zeros of the denominator.